# How to deserialize json string to a domain object?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7

I am trying to convert the following json into a domain object .

**JSON:**

```
[{"name":"McDonalds","deals":[{"desc":"Onion Rings free with Double Cheese burgers"}],"geometry":{"lat":13.073412,"lng":80.221393}},{"name":"JusSportz","deals":[{"desc":"20% off on Wilson Rackets"}],"geometry":{"lat":13.073231,"lng":80.221181}}]
```

**Model:**

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Deal
    {
        [DataMember(Name="name")]
        public string Store { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="deals")]
        public Offer[] Offers {get; set;}

        [DataMember(Name="geometry")]
        public GeoCoordinate Location { get; set; }

    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Offer
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string deal;
    }
```

I tried the ***DataContractJsonSerializer*** that is in the System.Runtime.Serialization.Json namespace and there is apparently no way to convert a string into an object. Are there any other libraries which allow me to get this done? Or is there a way to get this done using this library (by converting the Json string to some intermediate format.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I deserialize JSON back to my domain objects.

```
using (var reader = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("YourStringValue")))
{
     var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Deal));
     return (Deal)ser.ReadObject(reader);
}
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: i think so, I also think that i might be converting an array of deals while (incorrectly)  casting it to a Deal. I am getting an invalid cast exception. Ill try it out and accept it if its working

Comment: Make sure all of your classes which you are deserializing to have your data contract attributes.  If not, you may wind up with additional serialization issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change a bit Model:

```
[DataContract]
public class Deal
{
    [DataMember(Name="name")]
    public string Store { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="deals")]
    public Offer[] Offers {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Name="geometry")]
    public GeoCoordinate Location { get; set; }

}

[DataContract]
public class Offer
{
    [DataMember(Name="desc")]
    public string deal { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i dont think its a problem with the Model. I think it show im converting/parsing the JSON.